# How can the Info/Tool Tip text for a Windows Shell Object be retrieved on the consumer side?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, shell

The [Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a dated but robust API that, upon first glance, would seem to easily provide **Info / Tool Tip** text for a given shell item. The examples below demonstrate such tips within Windows Explorer.

[image: Windows Explorer Info Tips]

Although somewhat convoluted, the best way I found to retrieve tip text for a specific shell item is via a call to [IShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). In simplified pseudo-code:

```
// Using the parent shell item, get the IQueryInfo object for the specified single child pidl.
iQueryInfo = parent.GetUIObjectOf(child-pidl, IID-IQueryInfo)
// Get the info tip from the shell.
infoTipText = iQueryInfo.GetInfoTip(...)
```

This technique yields text that perfectly matches Windows Explorer, presumably formatted appropriately for locale where possible. The problem is, for some items GetUIObjectOf(...) returns error [ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For instance, in the examples above, A and B return tips but C causes said error.

Based on experimentation, it seems that the cases that choke in code all show up in Windows Explorer in the format below, as is the case with example C:

"Date Created: ~~~"

This may be relevant; perhaps there's way to obtain *this* text via some other call.

The following other techniques have been explored with no success so far:

- The shell item's System.InfoTipText property was queried and returns nothing.
- The shell item's System.PropList.InfoTip returns a template used to create a tip, e.g. "prop:System.Comment;System.DateCreated" (format discussed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#infotips)).
- KnownFolderDefinition.ToolTip does not help.

The best guess is that the formatted text returned from System.PropList.InfoTip could be passed into the shell and returned as a localized tip.